# How to force consecutive if blocks to execute one after the other?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I am trying to execute two if blocks one after the other in typescript.Both the if blocks consist of a service. But the condition for the second if block depends on a flag being set to true in the first if block.I know this is a little confusing but please take a look at the code below for a better understanding

```
export class Component{
condition1: boolean

constructor(private confirmationService: ConfirmationService) {}
submit()
{
    this.condition1 = false;
    if (somecondition)
    {
        if (this.condition1 == false)
        {
            this.confirmationService.confirm({
                message: Do you want to proceed?
                accept()
                {
                    // redirect to other page
                }
                reject()
                {
                    this.condition1 = true;
                }
            })
        }
        if (this.condition1 == true)
        {
            this.confirmationService.confirm({
                message: Do you want to quit?
                accept()
                {
                    //do something
                }
                reject()
                {
                    //do something
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
 }
```

So basically what is happening here is on clicking the SUBMIT button ,a confirm dialog box appears, this box will display different messages depending on the condition. If condition one is false then the dialog box displays the first message.If we click on YES on the dialog box then accept() is called , if we click on NO then reject() is called and there in reject() the condition1 is set to true.As soon as this condition is set to true we want the current dialog box to close(which is, that we want to come out of the service)and immediately reappear again with the second message in it(that is the second if condition is executed and the same service with a different message is called).How can I achieve this?

Comment: It would be less confusing if you decided which language you were writing in and formatted your code using your editor.

Comment: @AluanHaddad sorry about that , I am using typescript

Comment: I fixed the tags, but it's really hard to see what's going on since the context is missing. What is `this.service`? What does its `confirm` function return? Without that information I can only take guesses at the problem. Also, even the snippet itself is syntactically invalid. It will not parse.

Comment: there are also invalid "conditions" for the IFs: they're actually assignments. The first is never verified, the second always.

Comment: `if(condition1= false){`  - that line doesn't do what you think it does!  Do you know the difference between `=` and `==` operators ?

Comment: @selbie sorry that is if(condition1 == false)

Comment: @AluanHaddad this confirmation service is an inbuilt service in Primeng which is an Angular library.. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v5.2.7/#/confirmdialog

Comment: @Learner.123, don't add that in a comment. That should be part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

since you didn't share what `this.service` is, I only can assume it is a wrapper around `window.confirm`.

Every time you call the function `submit` you set `condition1 = false;` which makes the first check `if (condition1 == false)` useless.

Since confirm always only returns `true` or `false` you can do it like this

```
function submit() {
  const redirect = confirm('Do you want to proceed?');
  if (redirect) {
    self.location.href = 'bla/bla/bla';
  } else {
    const quit = confirm('Do you want to quit?');
    if (quit) {
      console.log('I want to quit');
    } else {
      console.log('I do not want to quit');
    }
  }
}

submit();
```

I hope this is what you were looking for. Once again, it is a hard guess without all the code.

EDITED:

After you edited your Post it makes more sense. I don't know much about Angular but the same logic should work though.

```
const redirect = this.confirmationService.confirm({
    message: 'Do you want to proceed?',
    accept: () => true, 
    reject: () => false
});

if (redirect) {
    self.location.href = 'bla/bla/bla';
  } else {
    const quit = this.confirmationService.confirm({
        message: 'Do you want to quit?',
        accept: () => true, 
        reject: () => false
    });
    if (quit) {
      console.log('I want to quit');
    } else {
      console.log('I do not want to quit');
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Andre, thank you so much for this..I have just edited the code and added a few more tags. This confirmation service is actually an inbuilt service to be used along with the confirm dialog of Prime ng. Prime ng is an angular library.Here https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v5.2.7/#/confirmdialog is what I am referring to

Comment: so I also edited the Post. Now the accept funtion returns `true` and reject `false`
This would result in the same logic.
If this library returns promises, then just `await`the results

Comment: this doesn't work because it jumps to if even before I click on yes/no (basically before the accept/reject functions return any value).Async/await I thought would work only when we need data from the server...can't figure put how to use await here..but thank you so much for the help:-)